# Class variable undefined inside function

Tags: typescript, function, settimeout, angular8

Just trying to learn Angular 2+ (8 specifically) and for the life of me, I can't understand why a class variable is 'undefined' inside a class function, but accessible if I write the function with ES6 style.

I tried setting in constructor instead, but that doesn't make sense.

```
export class GameControlComponent implements OnInit {

    myVar;
    counter = 0; 

    constructor() {}  ngOnInit() {}

    handleClickStart() {

        this.myVar = setInterval(this.myFunc, 1500);
    }

    myFunc() {
        this.counter++;
        console.log(this.counter);  
    }
}
```

Once 'handleClickStart' is called, this outputs NaN every 1.5 seconds. Why????
I would have expected 1 2 3....

Implementing handleClickStart this way gives me the desired results:

```
handleClickStart() {    
    this.myVar = setInterval(() => {
      console.log(this.counter + 1);
      this.counter++;
    }, 1500);
}
```

But still can't figure out why it didn't work out the first way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Answer (score 6):

This behaviour has to do with scopes, arrow functions,`this` and how Javascript functions/objects work.

Functions in JavaScript run in a specific context and using `this` accesses the current context. `this.counter` in the sample code is not available/defined inside `setInterval()` function, so we get `undefined`.

Now, in **Arrow functions**, things are special/different. Arrow Functions always lexically bind the context (Lexical Scoping means that it uses `this` from the code that contains the Arrow Function.) and therefore `this` will refer to the originating context, ie the class.

A simpler example might make it more clear.

```
const obj = {
  myVar: 'foo',
  myFunc: function() { 
    console.log('Actual Variable value: ',this.myVar)  

    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('Set timeout using Arrow function: ',this.myVar)
    }, 1000);
    setTimeout(function () {
      console.log('Set timeout using Normal function: ',this.myVar)
    }, 1000);
  }
}
obj.myFunc();
```

**Output**

```
Actual Variable value: foo
Set timeout using Arrow function:  foo
Set timeout using Normal function:  undefined
```

Read more

1. [Arrow functions](https://medium.com/tfogo/advantages-and-pitfalls-of-arrow-functions-a16f0835799e)
2. [this keyword](https://codeburst.io/all-about-this-and-new-keywords-in-javascript-38039f71780c)